# How to find out the function of a negatively skewed curve to solve for Y based on X in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, math, equation

I would like to find the function of the following plot so that I may find the Y value for any given X.
This data frame is supposed to look like a negatively skewed distribution curve in order to create a score (Y), for a given X.

```
df = data.frame(x = c(12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40),
                y = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 35, 75, 125, 175, 225, 275, 325, 370, 405, 440, 470, 480, 450, 385, 300, 200, 130, 90, 60, 35, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20))
        
        
ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 2)
```

[Negatively skewed curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8AQK.png)

I am unsure how to 1. solve for Y based on X? & 2. Calculate the function of the curve for use in other programs, is there a package that helps with this?
I have tried to solve this issue using lines of best fit in Excel but as the curve is a bit more complex there doesn't seem to be a tool that helps.

Comment: Have you tried the `fitdistrplus` package?

Comment: If you just want to linearly interpolate between points, you can do `f <- approxfun(df$x, df$y)` and then predict values with `f(19.5)`. But if you want to model the data with some function, you should be more clear on exactly how you want to model your data. You should probably ask for statistical advice first from [stats.se].

Comment: Do you need the function to be in the form of an explicit equation (e.g. `y =  a + b*x + c*x^2`)?  How do you plan to export the function for use in other predictions? (e.g. `spline` can give you predicted points on a smoothly interpolated curve spaced as finely as you want; `splinefun` will return a function that returns the `y` value for any specified `x` value)

Comment: Your data are not consistent with using the `distribution` tag — probability distributions are required to have an area of 1. Given your data values, you’re trying to do curve fitting, not distribution fitting.

Comment: You get a very close fit by summing two normal distributions. The model `mod <- nls(y ~ A * dnorm(x, B, C) + D * dnorm(x, E, G) + 20, data = df, start = list(A = 5000, B = 26, C = 4, D = 1000, E = 22, G = 1))` looks very close.